# Facebook Newsfeed 30 Day Search

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How do is search for news feed data upto 30 days using facebook api? I've read the documentation, but I'm confused, I want to know a solid way which can give me results against a keyword or a users newsfeed activity in the past 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

Try with *since* parameter like this
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?since=20100406&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN